# Visual Studio 2008 asking to save changes to .SLN file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, solution

My visual studio keeps prompting me to save the project to an `.SLN` file when I close it, but I'm not sure why.

Any ideas?  My ASP.net doesn't need a "solution file" as such.

It is showing my solution as the name 'Z', which is the drive letter I have chosen to map, which takes it straight to my code.

[image]

Comment: Do you really need to use VS 2008? If not I would tell you to upgrade to at least VS 2010. We already have VS 2012 RTM.

Comment: Coulton: VS needs a solution regardless. If you don't have one it will create a `new` one for you and ask you to save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not got a solution file then Visual Studio will create one for you, and that is what it is asking you about saving. If you open the project using the project file and not the solution file, chances are it will create a new solution file for you and then prompt you again to save it. I suggest you let it save the solution file, and then use that solution file in future to open the project.

Answer (score 4):

By default Visual Studio always creates a Solution file so that it can keep track of any projects you may add to the Solution (a Solution is just a collection of Projects) in the future.

There's no way around that. Simply let it save the `sln` file to the directory of your choosing.